# Angular 2 Class Binding

Tags: angular, binding

I am very new to this and trying to understand things from the below piece of Angular 2 template code.

```
<label for=”productNameInput”>Product Name</label> 
<input type=”text”
id=”productNameInput” 
placeholder=”Product Name”
[ formControl]=”myForm. get ( ’productName ’)” 
[ (ngModel) ] = ”productName”>
```

I have 2 questions:

- Which attributes should be defined in corresponding class?
- What is that braces around the ngModel is used for?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Not sure what class your are referring to

Comment: Read [Binding syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [(ngModel)]

> [[( )] = BANANA IN A BOX](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---)
>
> The [(x)] syntax combines the brackets of property binding, [x], with the parentheses of event binding, (x).

This is Two way data binding in Angular , Means to say whether you are making changes in controller side or view side it will change their value in angular.

You can separate it as well in `attribute` binding and `event` binding. like this -

`[ngModel]` for attribute binding and `(ngModelChange)` for event binding

For more about two-way data binding you can refer to official documentation here -

- https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngmodel---two-way-binding-to-form-elements-with-ngmodel

> Which attributes should be defined in corresponding class?

`productName` here in your code is variable which you need to define in the class to bind the value to view part.

Answer (score 1):

In the component's logic you should define

```
myForm: FormGroup;

productName: string;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({ productName: '' });
}
```

You have to define it like that because of how the code is (poorly) written, but you can simplify it a lot.

The braces (and parenthesis) around `ngModel` refer to Angular's data binding :

- `[x]` means you **input** a value to the framework
- `(x)` means the framework **outputs** a value to you
- `[(x)]` is **two-way binding** : you can update the view by inputing a value, and your component's variable is updated when the value is outputted.

By the way, `formControl` and `ngModel` are duplicates, you should remove either of them.

Answer (score 0):

the braces around the ngModel indicates 2 way binding. 
Here the link for more info

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html